Bicep Azure Machine Learning add notebooks
I am trying to figure out how to automate the process of adding and removing Notebooks from a given Azure Machine Learning resource.
This notebook can be under a given user's folder and a folder created by the user also right? So how can we automate this process fully instead of manually only.
I thought it was Microsoft.MachineLearningServices workspaces/data, but I didn't find any example with it.
UPDATE 1:
After doing some research I found out that all notebooks are stored in a given Storage Account under FileShare and not container, so I created this Bicep to add the file automatically in the path I need:
@description('ADLSv2 subscription Id.')
param __adlsv2SubscriptionId string

@description('ADLSv2 resource group name.')
param __adlsv2ResourceGroupName string

@description('Name of the file as it is stored in the file share')
param __filename string

@description('Name of the file share')
param __fileShareName string

@description('Azure region where resources should be deployed')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Desired name of the storage account')
param __storageAccountName string

@description('References the existing storage account resource.')
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' existing = {
  name: __storageAccountName
  scope: resourceGroup(__adlsv2SubscriptionId, __adlsv2ResourceGroupName)
}
resource deploymentScript 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2023-08-01' = {
  name: 'uploadFile'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  properties: {
    azCliVersion: '2.52.0'
    retentionInterval: 'PT1H'
    environmentVariables: [
      {
        name: 'AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT'
        value: storageAccount.name
      }
      {
        name: 'AZURE_STORAGE_KEY'
        secureValue: storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value
      }
    ]
    scriptContent: 'az storage file upload --source /home/guilherme/${__filename} -s ${__fileShareName} --path teste'
  }
}

But I got this error:

I am uploading the file to CLI console but is not recognizing as a path for some reason, I have tried only notebook.ipynb also. If I run the command az storage file upload alone it works though.

Can you share the code tried so far?

Are you looking for only bicep approach. @Guilherme Matheus

The resource provider Microsoft.MachineLearningServices workspaces/data is used to create the data assets in Azure Machine learning service but not actually existed to deal with notebooks operations.
As detailed in this Blog, you can use Python SDK and also CLI approach alternatively to automate the adding and deleting the notebooks by using workspace datastores.
Below is the code for adding:
import azureml.core
from azureml.core import Workspace, Experiment, ComputeTarget, Datastore
import os
import azureml.data

workspace = Workspace.from_config(path="config.json")

datastore = Datastore.get(workspace, 'workspaceblobstore')
user_folder = 'myfirstfolder'

path = 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Downloads'
datastore.upload(src_dir=path, target_path=user_folder, overwrite=True)
print("Uploaded successfully.")



In order to delete, you can use the similar configuration as above and use datapath module for accessing the user folder path and delete them.
As I mentioned above, you can also use az storage blob upload-batch to upload the notebook file to the linked machine learning storage account container.
az storage blob delete-batch to delete the file from the notebook folder recursively.

Hi @Jahnavi, sorry for taking few days to reply because of holiday. I have updated my question with what I have tried so far. And thanks for this solution, keep it here so that everyone can see, but I would love to check a Bicep one also.

@GuilhermeMatheus Good to accept the solution if it has solved the problem. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO Link

It hadn't solved my problem as I asked in SO thread by using Bicep. By it is a workaround using another method, that's what I said above. I always accept answers when is correct.

There is no workaround with the bicep approach. @GuilhermeMatheus

I have shared one example that worked for me, using ADLSv2 resource since all notebooks are stored there. But I got an error when trying on CLI directly using bicep, but the command itself works.
